# Find the average number of steps to sort an array by randomly selecting two elements

Tags: sorting, statistics, static-analysis

I have sequence of an unique numbers from 1 to 10 in randomly order (for example: list = [7, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 10, 1, 9, 8]). I can choose two random number and if the list from left number larger then right number I swap them (for example 2 and 5  list[2] larger then list[5] so I'll swap them and etc).

Need to find average number of all choosings to order the sequence.

The algorithm should executed less then 1 second.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: "Average number of such steps". Are we counting the number of "choosings" or the number of "swaps"?

Comment: (What does `sequence of an unique numbers` mean? I spot two instances of `7` in the example.)

Comment: We are counting the number of choosings (all steps)

Comment: Average amount of choosings in the worst case input or in an average case input?

Answer (score 1):

Construct a directed graph on the set of all permutation of $1,\ldots,n$ (in your case $n = 10$). For each permutation $\pi$, add edges from $\pi$ to permutations obtained by swapping two elements which were in the wrong order. This graph is a DAG with a unique sink, which is the identity permutation $\mathrm{id}$.

You can now compute the expected number of steps using dynamic programming. The base case is $E(\mathrm{id}) = 0$. If $\pi \neq \mathrm{id}$ has outneighborhood $N(\pi)$, then $E(\pi)$ satisfies
$$
E(\pi) = 1 + \frac{\left(\binom{n}{2} - |N(\pi)|\right) E(\pi) + \sum_{\rho \in N(\pi)} E(\rho)}{\binom{n}{2}},
$$
and so
$$
E(\pi) = \frac{\binom{n}{2}}{|N(\pi)|} + \frac{1}{|N(\pi)|} \sum_{\rho \in N(\pi)} E(\rho).
$$

The running time for computing $E$ on the entire graph is proportional to $\binom{n}{2} n!$, which in the case of $n = 10$ amounts to 163,296,000.

Using this algorithm, I calculated the average number of steps to be
$$ \frac{45411226589}{352546425} \approx 129.$$
This also agrees with my experiments.

Answer (score 0):

The average number is hard, an upper bound isn’t.

You have n numbers, therefore n(n-1) / 2 pairs of numbers. On average half of those pairs are in the wrong order. You need to figure out the distribution for that.

Now if you have k pairs in the wrong order, the probability of picking two random numbers in the wrong order is 2k / n / (n-1). If you pick two numbers in the wrong order and exchange them, the number of incorrectly ordered pairs goes down at least by one. So you expect n(n-1)/2k picks to go from k inversions to k-1 or fewer. (The “fewer” makes it hard to analyse).

Comment: I simulated it and find that distribution has a function like gamma-distribution and the average number of steps is located between 45 and ~140.